# Azure Data Explorer Checkpoint for Event Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

Helllo,

I'm ingesting data into Azure Data Explorer from Azure Event Hubs. Is there any configuration to ingest data from start of the queue, when I configured the ingestion the service only get data created before the configuration.

Another question, the Azure data Explorer uses checkpoint on EventHubs? If they Stop and Start again it will start from the point that was stoped?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When setting an Event Hub connection, ADX connection will start ingestion data arriving from time of its creation. You can suggest other configurations in [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer).
ADX use checkpoints when reading data, and will resume pulling data from the last checkpointed offset.